# How to parse PHP output that has multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

Ok so I'm using the BTC-E api and I'm calling it using this:

`$btc_usd = $BTCeAPI->getPairTicker('btc_usd');
// Show all information
print_r($btc_usd);`

and the output from the print is

`Array ( [ticker] => Array ( [high] => 640.04199 [low] => 605.00201 [avg] => 622.522 [vol] => 4217103.07651 [vol_cur] => 6723.54768 [last] => 636.1 [buy] => 636.1 [sell] => 635.999 [updated] => 1394418227 [server_time] => 1394418228 ) )`

how do I parse it so it just returns/prints the number for [last]

example:

so the output looks like "636.1"
so I can save it to a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an array of arrays.  The outer element is `ticker`:

```
$btc_usd["ticker"]["last"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$btc_usd = array(array('high' => 640.04199, 'low' => 605.00201,'avg' => 622.522,
 'vol' => 4217103.07651, 'vol_cur' => 6723.54768, 'last' => 636.1));

define('br', '<br />');

foreach($btc_usd as $array) {

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {

        if($key === 'last') {

            print($key . ': ' . $value . br);
        }

    }
}
```